# What is the PHP equivalent of this sha256 hashing method

Tags: python, php, sha256

I am trying to transfer a python method to PHP, but I keep getting different results.

`message` is an integer and `secret` is a string

The python script is

```py
hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'), struct.pack('>I', message), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
// 5d1fa4d6...
```

As far as I know, this should result in the same value

```php
hash_hmac('SHA256', $message, $secret)
// 5cd80ad7...
```

Comment: Not knowing python that much, I don't think the hashing is the problem. Instead you need to figure out what `secret.encode('utf-8')` does and how to replicate that in PHP, as well as `struct.pack('>I', message)`

Comment: @ChrisHaas  I guess so. These methods seem to convert the string and int to binary values. `hmac.new` works with this.

Answer (score 0):

`struct.pack('>I', message)` does more than converting the number to binary. It uses a big-endian 4-bytes representation.

The PHP equivalent is `pack('N', $message)`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.pack.php